# HDF5 Extend 1-D Dataset (C++)

Tags: c++, hdf5, hdf

I am trying to create a dataset in a HDF5 file and then extend it. I have a toy example, based largely on this [demo](https://bitbucket.hdfgroup.org/projects/HDFFV/repos/hdf5-examples/browse/1_10/C/H5D/h5ex_d_unlimadd.c). Here is my code:

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
#include <hdf5.h>

using namespace H5;    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const int DIM0 = 4;
  const int EDIM0 = 6;
  const int CHUNK0 = 1;
  const std::string FILE = "/tmp/test.h5";
  const std::string DATASET = "DS1";

  hid_t file, space, dset, dcpl; /* Handles */
  herr_t status;
  hsize_t dims[1] = {DIM0};
  hsize_t extdims[1] = {EDIM0 + DIM0};
  hsize_t maxdims[1];
  hsize_t chunk[1] = {CHUNK0};
  hsize_t start[1];
  hsize_t count[1];
  int wdata[DIM0];
  int wdata2[EDIM0];

  /*
   * Fill Dataset
   */
  for (int i = 0; i < DIM0; i++)
    wdata[i] = i + 1;

  file = H5Fcreate(FILE.c_str(), H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

  maxdims[0] = H5S_UNLIMITED;
  space = H5Screate_simple(1, dims, maxdims);
  dcpl = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
  status = H5Pset_chunk(dcpl, 1, chunk);

  dset = H5Dcreate(file, DATASET.c_str(), H5T_STD_I32LE, space, H5P_DEFAULT, dcpl, H5P_DEFAULT);

  status = H5Dwrite(dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &wdata[0]);

  /*
   * Extend the dataset.
   */
  status = H5Dset_extent(dset, extdims);
  space = H5Dget_space(dset);
  for (int i = 0; i < EDIM0; i++)
    wdata2[i] = 100 - (i + 1);

  status = H5Sselect_all(space);

  /*
   * Subtract a hyperslab reflecting the original dimensions from the
   * selection.  The selection now contains only the newly extended
   * portions of the dataset.
   */
  start[0] = DIM0;
  count[0] = EDIM0;
  status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(space, H5S_SELECT_SET, start, NULL, count, NULL);

  status = H5Dwrite(dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, space, H5P_DEFAULT, &wdata2[0]);

  status = H5Dclose(dset);
  status = H5Sclose(space);
  status = H5Fclose(file);
}
```

Now this creates a HDF file with the following dataset:

[image]

The [1,2,3,4] is fine, this is the original data. However, I would then expect it to continue [99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94]. Instead, it writes as if it were starting at position 0 in the array and then puts nonsense in the remaining cells. I can actually hack this problem away by putting:

```
status = H5Dwrite(dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, space, H5P_DEFAULT, &wdata2[0]-DIM0);
```

but this is a horrible hack. I strongly suspect that I am doing something wrong in the line where I `H5Sselect_hyperslab`, but I'm not sure what exactly...

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I will never understand, you cannot use `H5S_ALL` in the second write command. HDF5 then applies the same offsets as you use for the file position, resulting in buffer overruns. You have to use a separate memory space descriptor. This works:

```cpp
hid_t mspace = H5Screate_simple(1, count, count);
status = H5Dwrite(dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, mspace, space, H5P_DEFAULT, wdata2);
H5Sclose(mspace);
```